# Assume that $k$ is a particular integer. Is $2k − 1$ odd?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Hello I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how $2k-1$ is odd.

My solution shows this:

> Yes $2k-1$ is odd!
>
> $2k − 1 = 2(k − 1) +1$ and $k − 1$ is an integer because it is a difference of integers.

This is my understanding. An odd number is represented as $2k+1$ so...

> $2k-1$
>
> $2(k-1) +1$
>
> Refer to $k-1$ as $n$
>
> $2(n)+1$

Why can we substitute $k-1$ for $n$? Which operations on an integer equal to an integer?

Comment: The substitution is just a change of names. However, what is important is the claim that $n$ is an integer. This is due to the property that $k$ being an integer implies that $k-1$ is an integer too.

Comment: What is your working definition for an odd number? If you use the definition, "an integer that is not divisible by 2", then because $2k$ is divisible by 2, the number before and after it will not be.

Comment: You probably need to read more carefully the definition of "odd number", paying attention not only to algebraic expressions but also to words. An integer $x$ is odd if and only if **there exists** some integer $k$ such that $x=2k+1$. There merely has to be **some** such $k$, not necessarily the number that you (or your teacher or the textbook) happened to call $k$.  If you've got an integer that you call $k$, then $k-1$ is another perfectly good integer, and so $2(k-1)+1$ is odd.

Answer (score 3):

You need to find an integer $m$ so that
$$
2k-1=2m+1
$$
to show that $2k-1$ is odd. Solving for $m$ or by inspection, take $m=k-1$.

Answer (score 2):

**Any** integer ($k$) multiplied by two is even (by definition of even).
**Any even** integer ($2k$) increased by one ($2k+1$), or diminished by one ($2k-1$) is odd (by definition of odd).

Told in other words, even integers are at distance $2$ from each other, same are the odd ones, and they are interleaved.